# Polar Area Chart

Tags: graph, chart.js, pie-chart, powerbi

I have got a simple table like this

```
Group     Weight    Reached
------    ------   ---------
Group1     35%       75%
Group2     40%       37%
Group3     10%      120%
Group4     15%       66%
```

Where the 'weight' represent sector of a pie chart and 'reached' is the área reached in this group.

I need to do a polar pie chart like this

[image]

I don't know how can I do it. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: How is a "reached" percentage that is greater than 100% handled visually?

Comment: In this case the area sector radius is greater than the circle pie

Comment: Some thing like [this example](https://www.google.es/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwisjNS9wJLUAhVGHxoKHZD5CmAQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2F57283719%40N07%2F6960601654&psig=AFQjCNE-wtIyehSw4ZhwgaZ0D0J8EGfx5A&ust=1496057956908353) where circle represent 100%

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've got it.

I found that what I was looking for it was an "Aster Plot" where you can set the outerRadius to a determinated value.

[image]

Thanks!